# Generate a word table from tab paragraphs

Tags: vba, parsing, ms-word, tabs

I am trying to generate a word table from tabs, that are under a Headline "Change Control:". The "table" has four columns like this:

Col1 tab Col2 tab Col 3 tab Col4 return

Can someone give me an example or an approach how to do this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim doc As Document
 Dim k As Integer
 Dim start As Boolean
 Debug.Print "Start"

 Set doc = ActiveDocument
 start = False
 For k = 1 To doc.Paragraphs.Count
    Set para = doc.Paragraphs(k)
    If para.Style = doc.Styles(wdStyleHeading1) Then
        'para.
        'para.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        'MsgBox para.Range.Text
        If Left(Trim(para.Range.Text), Len("Change Control")) = "Change Control" Then
            start = True
        End If

        If Left(Trim(para.Range.Text), Len("Change Control")) <> "Change Control" Then
            start = False
        End If

        ' If start Then

        ' End If
    End If


 Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: research the ConvertToTable method.

Comment: A good approach thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :-) I was on my iPad when I wrote that last night, so couldn't go into detail. For the forum administration I've written out more information as an "Answer" so the discussion can be closed...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConvertToTable method to turn text in delimited format into a Table in Word. Important is to use ANSI 13 (vbCR / paragraph mark) as the row separator. You can use any symbol as the cell separator.